# how can i converting listview to listview.builder

Tags: flutter

```
    body: Container(
      color: Color(0XfffFEF5F1),
        child: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          children:
           Categories_data.map((categoryData) => TopicItems(id: categoryData.id, title:  categoryData.title,)
        ).toList(),
        ),
    ),
```

categories_data is file that contain a list of data

Categories_data =

const [

Category(
id: 'c1',
title: 'say hello',
),

Category(
id: 'c2',
title: 'say goodbye',
),

]

TopicItems is just widget

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The equivalent with builder would be

```
body: Container(
  color: Color(0XfffFEF5F1),
    child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
      itemCount: Categories_data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>           
        TopicItems(id: Categories_data[index].id, title:  Categories_data[index].title,)
    ),
),
```